# Making an invisible pressure plate

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to build a teleporter. I want the player to be teleported from the first sign(left) to the right sign(right). So, when the player steps on the red wool on the left, he will automatically be teleported to the red wool on the right. I do not want to use any pressure plats.It might work with the testfor comment, but I didn't figure out, put that only works with a radius. BTW I'm in 1.10.2 bou I could probably change the version if necessary. 
[image]

[image]
The testfor command block should activate the teleport command block,when the player is detected.
Now, I'm not really the expert, so I know non of the commands that you would need to build this construction. Please help, I would highly appreciate it!
If you need any more details, ask me!

Comment: I don't know about command blocks, but you could easily output a redstone signal to activate one using an old school player detector. A cow with a nametag standing on a pressure plate below the spot indicated. The mob will not move if no players are in distance, but once you stand on that block and the cow is "just" in range (a few dozen blocks below that spot) and it will begin pathfinding. Since it is stuck in one spot it will jump up and down on the plate, allowing you to extract a signal. Of course this will only work if you have the room below the spot(s), and nothing else is down there.

Comment: I did that in version 1.8, but I wanted it to be with command blocks, since it is definitely possible. I just don't know how ;(

Comment: Yeah I stopped playing on PC back when we had to use the North/South exploit just to open double doors on the same tick (before redstone repeaters were introduced) so I've been playing on console since then and don't have any experience with command blocks haha. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer though. Like I said I appreciate every comment! :D

Comment: Also you could like the topic so more people see it!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I'm pretty sure you would be able to find some starter points on the site, there are a lot of questions that incorporate this sort of behaviour. The wiki also us a good place to look :)

Comment: Also, the voting system is not used the same way as other sites, it is used to identify useful or good questions and answers. If other users have a similar question, instead of posting the sane question, they can upvote your post instead :)

Comment: The first sign(left) to the right sign (right), xD

Comment: @Tuffi Can't you use tripwire?

Answer (score 2):

**[1.10.2]**

With the use of target selectors and a single command block, this is possible.
I am going to explain the method to do this for future use.

So there are two teleportation commands:

```
/tp
```

and

```
/teleport
```

tp is the one that we will be using as it calculates relative coordinates to the entity that the command was executed upon, whereas /teleport executes it upon the relative coordinates of the entity that is performing the command (i.e the player).

So now we have the following command. Aint that great :D

```
/tp
```

Now the normal context for this command comes like this:

```
/tp <player name> <player name>
```

or

```
/tp <player name> <X> <Y> <Z>
```

X Y Z are coordinates.

Instead of the above method's we will instead use **target selectors**, which come in three different types:

```
@a
```

executes all of the players.

```
@r
```

executes a random player.

```
@e
```

executes all entities (everything mob type)

```
@p
```

executes the nearest player (to where the command is being executed)

In this instance we will be using @a (all players). So now we have this command: :D

```
/tp @a
```

Ok dont type that in chat yet. Now we must add the target selector:

```
/tp @a[]
```

Now these square brackets are where the selectors will go.

```
/tp @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z]
```

Ok so you add the coordinates that you want your pressure plate to go in the X Y Z zones (THE CAPITALS GODDAMNIT).
Now we must add one final selector:

```
/tp @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=1]
```

The r selector stands for "radius". So this won't exactly execute in the radius of one block it feels a lot more a sphere the size pf one block. Now we add the coordinates that we want the player to go to:

```
/tp @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=1] X Y Z
```

Change the second X Y Z to the coordinates the player needs to go to. To get coordinates press F3 for the debug menu it can be found there.

Finally, paste the command into a repeating command block thats always active. I can see you already know how to get them, but for you **NOOBS** out there I'll help yall out. /give @p command_block

I made an example of the machine:

[image: here]

Now the inside of the command block should look like this:

[image: HERE]

The coordinates in the picture are just an example.

Now for you lazy peeps... /tp @a[x=1,y=1,z=1,r=1] X Y Z

Comment: relative coordinates would look smoother, also if you include player facing direction you can have it bi-directional (mostly, can't walk backwards through it)

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what the heck Experimental Rocket just said. Why don't you just use something like /execute @e[type=Player] ~ ~ ~ detect wool 14 ~ ~-1 ~  0 /tp YourPlayerNameHere X Y Z ? This will make it so that whenever you step on red wool, you get teleported to your X Y and Z. Don't forget to change YourPlayerNameHere to your username!

(This command goes in a repeating command block)

Comment: while this would work, it requires the wool block, @ExperimentalRocket 's answer would work without

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hbnXDt7xsE)

It has a method that utilizes the fact that an animal will not move unless a certain number of blocks close to the player. It works on a basis where a cow is surrounded by pressure plates, and when someone gets within the limit, the cow moves, triggering whatever your contraption is.