# How do I make a command that triggers when I step on a block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been looking this up and watching videos on it for a week now. Nothing has helped! Please, does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: I'm doing a teleport command btw

Comment: What resources did you find before giving up on your search? Sharing your research helps everyone - it shows that you've taken the time to help yourself before posting, and it stops us from reiterating answers that you may have already tried.

Comment: This is typically done with a pressure plate or a repeating command which runs for a particular area and teleports all players in the area. See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303331/making-an-invisible-pressure-plate. If you can't seem to trigger your command, it may also just be doing nothing. Have you tried just making your command block /say 'Hello World' first?

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Comment: If you think my answer works for you, you can press the check mark button below the "vote" buttons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a simple fix to this:

Have Repeating command block set to Always Active, with this command:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ stone 0 tag @s add block
```

Next, have a command chain set to Conditional, Always active with command:

```
setblock x y z redstone_block
```

Next, have a command chain set to Conditional, Always active. Its delay in ticks is 2, with this command:

```
setblock x y z air
```

One block next to coordinates `x y z`, place a command block with command:

```
tp *@a[tag=block] x' y' z'
```

You can replace `stone` with the block of choice, and `x' y' z'` with the coordinates of the location where players are teleported to.

I hope this helps.

Comment: For modern versions of minecraft, you must use `execute at @a if block ~ ~-1 ~ stone run <INSERT COMMAND HERE>`

Comment: @David Callanan if I'm doing a teleport command do I put cordinates and an @?

Comment: By @ i mean like @p @a @s

Comment: @fasterthanlight what  kind of redstone/command circuit should I use?

Comment: @LegoLuna What do you want to happen when a player steps on a block?

Comment: @fasterthanlight Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice

Comment: @fasterthanlight I want them to teleport to cordinates

Comment: what kind of redstone/command circuit should I use if I want them to teleport when they step on the block

Comment: @LegoLuna That is included in the answer. If you think my answer works for you, you can press the check mark button on my post, under the "vote" buttons.

Comment: I have a few questions. What is a command chain, and what cordinates do I put in the first 2 x y z?

Comment: @LegoLuna The first 2 coords (`x y z`) should be the same, you can make it anything you want. `x' y' z'` is the coords that player will be sent to.

Comment: @fasterthanlight This worked great!